# How to update the changed username in session variable without logout or session destroy

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

**Question:**

How to update the changed username in session variable without logout or session destroy ?

**For Example:**

I am login with username "Ram" and this username storing in session variable User_Name,after logged in i am changing my username "Ram" into "Kumar". So this newly changed username should get updated in session variable User_Name automatically without logout from my account.

**Sample Controller Code for Login:**

```
function check_database($password)
{
  // Field validation succeeded.  Validate against database
  $username = $this->input->post('username');

  // query the database
  $result = $this->civic_soft_model->login($username, $password);

  if($result)
  {
    $sess_array = array();
    foreach($result as $row)
    {
      $sess_array = array(
        'UID' => $row->UID,
        'User_Name' => $row->User_Name,
        'User_Type' => $row->User_Type,
        'User_OTP' => $row->User_OTP
        // 'Login_Status' => $row->Login_Status
        // 'Node_Id' => $row->Node_Id
      );
      $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);
    }
    return TRUE;
  }
  else
  {
    $this->form_validation->set_message('check_database', 'Invalid username or password');
    return false;
  }
}
```

**NOTE:**

I am using PHP,MySQL and CodeIgniter MVC Framework.

**Please Help Me Friends...**

Comment: what is your question? you can update the session variables at any point in time.

Comment: How to change the session variable value in codeIgniter

Comment: just follow the code in the codeigniter manual or that has been posted. but whats important to understand - when you change/update a session variable - the change is reflected - in the NEXT page. same for setting a session variable - you set it on page one - you can check it on page two. this is especially important to understand when creating log-in / log-out. its also why you will see some people do a redirect after a session change like a log out - to force the browser to go to a second page.

Answer (score 1):

I actually see what the problem is now. You are setting 'logged_in' to be an array. Not sure if that's common, but what I usually do is set 'logged_in' as a boolean and I set userdata the data that I need in another array.

However, for you case you can try this:

```
  $newUserData = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
  if (is_array($newUserData)) {
      $newUserData['User_Name'] = $new_username;
      $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $newUserData);
  }
```

For better usability, I would addd a function to `$this->civic_soft_model` called "updateUser" or something of that nature. And when that function is called, you can update all of the session data that you need to.

Comment: @user3482165, did the updated function work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Insert this function to your controller and call it whenever there is an update made on the users information.

```
//$new_username : the username inputted by user when he is trying to update his account
function update_session($new_username){
    $this->session->set_userdata('User_Name', $new_username);
}
```

Comment: This looks like a rushed answer. There is no function name and the 'session->userdata' function will only return the session data, not update it as asked in the question.

Comment: Sorry for that... I kinda confused both.

Comment: No problem. Looks better now. Don't think it needs it's own function however. If there's an update call now, the username update may be best going there. (Not saying your answer is incorrect, but just a note for user3482165 on where to put the session update.

Comment: But it still is better going, both ways can be done it 1 line, the advantage of a function though is that when we want to add something that needs to be done together with updating just the username, then function will come on handy.

Comment: How to call this function? I am using $this->update_session(); to call this function. But it's not changing the session value still.

Comment: Do you not have a function to update your database record? The update should happen at the same time as that. Otherwise, the session will be updated but when the user is authenticated again, it will still have the older username. Also, @user, the function is great, however, it's very abstract. As you can see from the question "How to call this function?". Does it go in a model, helper, controller? Does he need to load that model, controller or helper? There are too many unknowns for my well being with that function.